# How to "make a copy" of GoogleSheet with python?

Tags: python, google-sheets

I wish to automate getting a copy of an original google-sheet using Python. The Sheet Has an Appscript bound to it as well, therefore I want to make a copy of the entire project and not just the spreadsheet.

(When done manually the copy of the spreadsheet is made via File->"Make a Copy" , this gives me a copy of the AppScript as well.)

I cannot figure out how to this via gspread,pygsheets or google-sheets-API.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Sheets API, you could use Drive API instead to copy a file (with the script bound to it). This does not work only on Sheets, but on other files as well.

You can start reading from the documentation here:

[Drive API | Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python)

And this is the specific method:

[Files: copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and created a pypi module, you can check it at https://pypi.org/project/google-api-support/ and https://github.com/vperezb/google-api-support.

After dealing with credentials stuff you can simply do as follows.

```
from GoogleApiSupport import drive
new_file_id = drive.copy_file('ID_FILE_TO_COPY', 'New file title')
```